# Lwjgl text rendering and simple 2d rendering

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, text-rendering

I have a problem with switching between 2D 3D and 2D for text rendering.
When I switch to 2D to render simple quads, and then I switch to 2D for tekst rendering, the quads will be removed.
I have tried several things with my code, and the problem is `glBlendFunc`
This is my code to initialize simple 2D rendering:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
```

And here is my code to initialize 2D rendering for text:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glClearDepth(1);

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);

// This is the problem line
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GL11.glViewport(0,0, 800, 600);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

After I have switched to 2d for rendering text, the simple 2d shapes will not be drawn again after the screen is cleared in the next rendering loop.
How can I solve this problem?
I got this code from http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not draw anything after text rendering initialization code in lwjgl (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336837/can-not-draw-anything-after-text-rendering-initialization-code-in-lwjgl-java)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue before with rendering 3D with 2D what i did was make 3 separate methods. In your case 3 might work and how you would use this is by calling your 2D rendering first, then the rendering so it for my example I am using the names setOrphoOn and setOrphoOff On being 2D and off being 3D (same rules apply i guess)

[Click here to see example of how it is done](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/128520376/Stack%20Overflow%20Examples/Lwjgl%20text%20rendering%20and%20simple%202d%20rendering.txt)

Sorry i didn't < code > and < /code > because this site does not like my code formatting so iv had to do this it should just open in a browser containing the code

Furthermore Sorry if this doesn't explain easily and that the code doesn't format correctly??? but that's how I do it and it does work for me feel free to test setOrphoOnOff at your own accord

Comment: Formatting code is done simply by indenting it once. There should be a question mark on the editor toolbar that has formatting instructions.

Comment: I tried indenting but it would work for half the code the link is to a txt that i put in my drop box