# Can not draw anything after text rendering initialization code in lwjgl (Java)

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

Hello I have two seperate initialization codes to switch between rendering 2d shapes and (2d) text in lwjgl. If the initialization code for rendering text is executed, the 2d shapes will not be drawn. I tried everything, and I found the problem line: `GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

After I have done something with the glBlendFunc, I can only render tekst, and switching to the initialization code for rendering 2d shapes won't work anymore.

Here are my 2 codes:

Simple 2d rendering:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
```

Code for rendering text:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glClearDepth(1);

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);

// Problem line
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GL11.glViewport(0,0, 800, 600);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

I think the problem is just a wrong OpenGl state, but how can I put the states right?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find out the issue without access to your whole code, thus I can just post some guesses:

1. Do you clear the colour and depth buffer (`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`)?
2. Do you enable GL_TEXTURE_2D when drawing textures and disable it otherwise?

I use the same blend function and can draw images just fine (it's the most used blend function for drawing images that have transparency).

PS: This are the only settings I use to draw any kind of 2D stuff (I'm using vertex array objects and shaders for rendering though):

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Yes, I do glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); in each rendering loop. I am not using textures because I could not get to it by this error.

Comment: @user2190492 but you're using textures for drawing text - you even manually enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` before rendering text. Thus I ask whether you disable it before rendering untextured stuff.

Comment: Yes I enable it before I draw untextured stuff.

Comment: @user2190492 *disable. Could you post some more code please? Post all OpenGL calls if possible.

Comment: I learned how to render text on this site: [link](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL)

Answer (score 1):

Here is more code

**Renderer.java**

```
package game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_BLEND;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_CONSTANT_COLOR;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_ONE;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Renderer {

    private static boolean in3d = false;

    public static void initText2D() {

        in3d = false;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();

        //GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glClearDepth(1);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GL11.glViewport(0,0, 800, 600);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    public static void init2D() {

        in3d = false;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // Test
        //GL11.glBlendFunc(GL_CONSTANT_COLOR, GL_ONE);

    }

    public static void init3D(float fov, float aspect, float near, float far) {

        in3d = true;

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    }

    public static void begin(int shape) {

        GL11.glBegin(shape);
    }

    public static void end() {

        GL11.glEnd();
    }

    public static void setVertex3(float x, float y, float z) {

        if(!in3d) {

            System.out.println("[WARNING] > Adding 3d vertex but there is no 3d context");
        }

        GL11.glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }

    public static void setColor(float r, float g, float b) {

        GL11.glColor3f(r, g, b);
    }

    public static void setVertex2(float x, float y) {

        if(in3d) {

            System.out.println("[WARNING] > Adding 2d vertex while in 3d context");
        }

        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);

    }
}
```

**Button.java (example of how I draw a button in lwjgl)**

```
package gui;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2f;
import game.Renderer;
import game.TextRenderer;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
public class Button extends AbstractButton {

    private String text;

    public Button(int x, int y, int w, int h, String text) {

        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
        this.setWidth(w);
        this.setHeight(h);
        this.text = text;

        paintElement();
    }

    public Button(String text) {

        this.text = text;
        paintElement();
    }

    public Button() {

        paintElement();
    }

    public void paintElement() {

        Renderer.init2D();

        Renderer.begin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        Renderer.setColor(this.getColorR(), this.getColorG(), this.getColorB());

        Renderer.setVertex2(this.getX(), this.getY());
        Renderer.setVertex2(this.getX() + this.getWidth(), this.getY());
        Renderer.setVertex2(this.getX() + this.getWidth(), this.getY() + this.getHeight());
        Renderer.setVertex2(this.getX(), this.getY() + this.getHeight());

        Renderer.end();

        Renderer.initText2D();
        TextRenderer.drawString(this.getX() + 10, this.getY() + 10, this.text);
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
package game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor3f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glOrtho;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2f;

import java.awt.Font;

import gui.Button;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

public class Main {

    private int gamestate;
    private boolean closeRequested;

    private static Camera cam;
    private static User user;

    public Main() {

        createUser();
        createDisplay();
        createCamera();
        gameLoop();
        cleanUp();
    }

    private void createUser() {


    }

    private void createDisplay() {

        try {

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setResizable(true);
            Display.create();


        } catch (LWJGLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCamera() {


    }

    private void gameLoop() {

        while(!closeRequested) {

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glLoadIdentity();

            //Renderer.init2D();
            /*
            // Test 2d line
            Renderer.init2D();
            Renderer.setColor(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
            Renderer.begin(GL11.GL_LINE);
            Renderer.setVertex2(0, 0);
            Renderer.setVertex2(100, 100);
            Renderer.end();
            */

            // set the color of the quad (R,G,B,A)
            glColor3f(0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

            // draw quad
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex2f(100,100);
                glVertex2f(100+200,100);
                glVertex2f(100+200,100+200);
                glVertex2f(100,100+200);
            glEnd();

            checkInput();

            Button b = new Button(100, 100, 100, 30, "Test");

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(10);
        }

        return;
    }

    private void checkInput() {

        // Check keyboard, mouse and other input

        if(Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            closeRequested = true;
        }

        return;
    }

    private void cleanUp() {


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I spot is that you clear the display in init2D/initText2D, i.e. whenever you switch between the modes you discard everything drawn before. Thus when the Button starts to draw its text it clears the two rectangles that were drawn before.

Comment: I removed the 2 lines of code in each method (init2d and initText2d) but it is still not working. I searched on google and I read that slick changes some OpenGl states when drawing text. I think my problem can also be solved if someone could give me an example how to draw text and 2d shapes so I can see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!

This is my new (working) code:

**init2d**

```
GL11.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

// solution
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

**initText2d**

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glClearDepth(1);

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GL11.glViewport(0,0, 800, 600);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

I think the problem was that slick uses textures for text rendering, and I had to enable the textures or bind them to 0.
See this: http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4019.0

Comment: Good to see that you could solve your problem yourself :) - BTW: If you ever want to know the source code of some function that you call (e.g. from `TrueTypeFont`), hold down `ctrl` and click on the function (this works in Eclipse, the combination might be different in other IDEs), and you will be taken to the source code automatically. If you get an error message that the source is not available you should download it from their website and link it (the error message should tell you how).